# Exporting C++ Object from DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I am creating a wrapper DLL for boost containers (map, vecrtor, set..). In my application, I want to export the C++ object from the DLL to the client. So I am left with two option for exporting:

1. Export the C++ Class using `(_declspec)dllexport` and use in client.
2. Provide a abstract class with only pure virtual functions (like interfaces in COM) and export only a single method from the DLL (for instance `CreateMap`).

I am using the containers(map, vector..) extensively in the client.

Can any one please help me, which will be the best method for exporting?

Comment: map, vector and set are templates, how are you going to put those in DLL?

Comment: map, vector are private class members of the Dll

Comment: @user3283893 Because the question is on hold, I cannot post this as an answer, but take a look at https://github.com/jbandela/cppcomponents It is a C++11 header-only library that allows you to put C++ objects in DLL and be able to call them from other compiled exe or DLL even if they are compiled with a different C++ compiler or standard library. If you want to use it, let me know and I can help you get started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having C++ classes and STL containers at the DLL interface boundaries is very fragile and highly constraining for your clients: in fact, both the DLL and the client EXEs must be built with the *same* VC++ compiler version, and dynamically link to the *same* flavor of the CRT.

It's much safer and better practice to build DLLs exporting a **pure C interface**. Note that **you can use C++ *inside* the DLL boundaries** (this is basically what many Win32 C-interface APIs do).

As an alternative you may export pure C++ abstract classes (**interfaces**) from the DLL, which is basically what COM does.

You may find [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL) interesting.